# Multiply Rows Conditionally in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`

```
# Load Library
library(data.table)

# Generate Data

test_data <- data.table(
  year = c(2000,2000,2001,2001),
  grp  = rep(c("A","B"),2),
  value = 1:4
)
```

I want to multiply the values of group `A` with varying parameters over `year`. My attempt was using `sapply` with `fifelse` and a fixed value of 2, but it seems that this solutions is going to be messy if I want to vary this value over time.

```
multiply_effect <- sapply(
  1:nrow(test_data), function(i){
    
    fifelse(
      test = test_data$grp[i] == "A", test_data$value[i] * 2, test_data$value[i]
    )
  }
)
```

Lets say that I want to multiply the `value` of grp `A` with `2` in `2000` and by `3` in `2001` and keeping grp `B` as it is, then my desired `output`would be,

```
   year grp value new_value
1: 2000   A     1         2
2: 2000   B     2         2
3: 2001   A     3         9
4: 2001   B     4         4
```

Im looking for at `data.table`-solution only.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the factors for the years / groups you want to modify in another lookup `data.table` and update the main table with a join:

```
test_data <- data.table(
  year = c(2000,2000,2001,2001),
  grp  = rep(c("A","B"),2),
  value = 1:4
)

factor_lookup <- data.table(
  year = c(2000,2001),
  grp  = rep("A",2),
  factor = c(2,3)
)


test_data[factor_lookup ,value:=value*factor,on=.(year,grp)][]

    year    grp value
   <num> <char> <int>
1:  2000      A     2
2:  2000      B     2
3:  2001      A     9
4:  2001      B     4
```